# Can't get information from xml file (simplexml_load_file)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My xmlfile looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<METADATA xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MDR-DVD>
    <dvdTitle>Rambo First Blood Part II</dvdTitle>
    <releaseDate>1985 01 01</releaseDate>
    <genre>Actie</genre>
    <largeCoverParams>D:\Films\Rambo First Blood Part II\cover.jpg</largeCoverParams>
    <smallCoverParams>D:\Films\Rambo First Blood Part II\cover.jpg</smallCoverParams>
    <duratation>94</duratation>
    <title>
      <synopsis>Ex-Green Beret en Vietnamveteraan John Rambo zit inmiddels al drie jaar vast in een kamp waar hij zware arbeid moet verrichten als straf voor de gebeurtenissen uit 'First Blood'. Zijn voormalige kolonel Trautman komt hem opzoeken met een aanbod of nog vijf jaar zware arbeid, of een missie in Vietnam om een aantal Amerikaanse krijgsgevangenen te lokaliseren. John kiest voor het tweede. Hij komt onder commando te staan van Murdock, een man die niet het beste met John voorheeft...</synopsis>
    </title>
  </MDR-DVD>
</METADATA>
```

My php file looks like: (where description_file is the url to the xml-file)

```
$xml4=simplexml_load_file($description_file);
print_r($xml4);
echo $xml4->genre;
```

The print_r works, it shows the whole xml-file:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [MDR-DVD] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [dvdTitle] => Rambo First Blood Part II [releaseDate] => 1985 01 01 [genre] => Actie [largeCoverParams] => D:\Films\Rambo First Blood Part II\cover.jpg [smallCoverParams] => D:\Films\Rambo First Blood Part II\cover.jpg [duratation] => 94 [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [synopsis] => ...moviedescription... ) ) )
```

But i cant get the info from a tag, 
echo $xml4->genre; - returns nothing at all - not even an error

Whats wrong?

-- I noticed when I remove the metadata tag from the xml-file, the echo $xml4->genre; does work but I need that line :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<genre>` is a child of `<MDR-DVD>` and not a child of the root node. The PHP code should look like this:

```
$metadata = simplexml_load_file($filename);
echo $metadata->{"MDR-DVD"}->genre;
```

Comment: Maybe add an explanation: "You need to specify the whole path through all parent nodes towards your target node. And since one parent node contains invalid chars for a plain old PHP variable, the brackets notation is used here.

Comment: This works like a charm, I had tried this with [] instead of {} Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
echo $xml4->{MDR-DVD}[0]->genre
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php